# Three.js - strange mesh pixel error

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm using ThreeJS (r81) for creating an interactive helmet designer and ran into the following issue:

[image]

as you can see, there is a display error within the red mesh.
I tried using the .mtl file and the issue disappears if I change the mesh color the error occurs, I also asked our designer who made the helmet but he has no ideas.

any help appreciated!

Comment: This is a total guess. But it's so easy, it's worth trying first. Try setting the material to double sided. E.G. yourMaterial.side = THREE.DoubleSide; It looks like a lot of polygons and face winding order couldn't handle all surfaces.I'd also check to make sure there are no displacement maps being applied by the MTL that aren't being cleared. I'd set the color via a brand new material.